# Implications/Impact Analysis of increasing the transaction size to 64KB in tx_pool.go to support bigger bytecodes deployment

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-deployment, txpool

As I have increased the transaction size to 64KB in tx_pool.go and rebuilt geth to support bigger bytecodes deployment (i.e., bigger, more complex and sophisticated smart contracts), would like to know if there could be any unforseen implications/impact?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transaction size limits exist mainly to prevent denial of service attacks by filling up a node's txpool with huge transactions. They are not a consensus rule, and if you are able to survive such an attack, or it is not a practical attack vector for your network (as is the case for many private networks), then there should be no major downside to increasing it.

Comment: Great great answer. I am using private ethereum so dos is not an issue